# How to set active class on list of buttons

Tags: angular

I have an **Angular 2** app that has a component that contains a list of filter buttons.
One of them can be **active** at any one time. 
The button definitions come from some **json** and will one day be sent from the server.

My problem is how to set a style on the currently clicked button.
Should I set it in the click event handler? So how do I know which button was clicked?

My **Component** looks like this :

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output }  from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'tileFilter',
    template: require('./tileFilter.component.html'),
    styles: [require('.//tileFilter.component.scss').toString()]
})

export class TileFilterComponent {

@Output() onCategorySelected = new EventEmitter<number>();

public activeClass: string = "nonactive"

 private categories: any[] = [
    { "Id": 0, "Name": "All" },
    { "Id": 3, "Name": "Popup" },
    { "Id": 4, "Name": "Cafe" },
    { "Id": 5, "Name": "Pub or bar" },
    { "Id": 9, "Name": "Restaurant" }
];

    constructor() {}

    onClick(category:any){
        this.activeClass ="active";
        this.onCategorySelected.emit(<number>category.Id);
    }

}
```

And my **HTML** looks like this :

```
<ul class="tile-filters inline-list inline-list--sm unstyled-list collapse">
  <li *ngFor="let c of categories">
      <button class="button button--recede button--sm {{activeClass}}" (click)="onClick(c)">{{c.Name}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What's the common pattern for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The common pattern is to create a new variable to keep track of which button is clicked, to reassign that variable on a click event, and to bind the active class on whether or not the current button equals the selected button.

From the [Angular 2 tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#style-the-selected-hero):

```
//...

<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

//...

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;
  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by only modifying your html code and more over it is  angular 2 standard  as well.

```
    <li *ngFor=" let c of categories ">
          <button [class.active]="clicked === c" 
             (click)="clicked = (clicked === c ? null :c)">{{c.Name}}</button>
    </li>
```

[More Info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/add-class-to-active-element-angular-2.html)

Comment: This got me to where I needed to be. I came to this page to have the question answered for <button>, not for <li>. So although the selected answer answers the question best, I think THIS answer answers the subject of the post best.